# Why does my GetObjectRequest return a 403 Access Denied error when my Lambda has access to the S3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a Lambda function that makes a `GetObject` request to an S3 bucket.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at deserializeAws_restXmlGetObjectCommandError (/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:6284:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at /node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:6:20
    at /node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/middleware.js:11:20
    at StandardRetryStrategy.retry (/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/StandardRetryStrategy.js:51:46)
    at /node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:6:22
    at GetS3Data (/src/input.ts:21:26)
    at Main (/src/main.ts:8:34)
    at Runtime.run [as handler] (/handler.ts:6:9) {
  Code: 'AccessDenied',
  RequestId: '3K61PMQGW4825D3W',
  HostId: '5PpmWpu2I4WZPx37Y0pRfDAcdCmjX8fchuE+HLpUzy7uqoJirtb9Os0g96kWfluM/ctkn/mEC5o=',
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 403,
    requestId: undefined,
    extendedRequestId: '5PpmWpu2I4WZPx37Y0pRfDAcdCmjX8fchuE+HLpUzy7uqoJirtb9Os0g96kWfluM/ctkn/mEC5o=',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  }
}
```

I've given access to the Lambda function to make this request.

What is the issue?

`serverless.ts`

```
import type { AWS } from "@serverless/typescript";

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
    service: "affiliations",
    frameworkVersion: "2",
    custom: {
        esbuild: {
            bundle: true,
            minify: false,
            sourcemap: true,
            exclude: ["aws-sdk"],
            target: "node14",
            define: { "require.resolve": undefined },
            platform: "node",
        },
    },
    plugins: ["serverless-esbuild"],
    provider: {
        name: "aws",
        region: "us-east-2",
        runtime: "nodejs14.x",
        apiGateway: {
            minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
            shouldStartNameWithService: true,
        },
        environment: {
            AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: "1",
            NODE_OPTIONS: "--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000",
        },
        lambdaHashingVersion: "20201221",
        vpc: {
            securityGroupIds: ["<redacted>"],
            subnetIds: ["redacted>"],
        },
        iam: {
            role: {
                statements: [
                    {
                        Effect: "Allow",
                        Action: ["s3:GetObject"],
                        Resource: "<redacted>",
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    },
    useDotenv: true,
    // import the function via paths
    functions: {
        run: {
            handler: "handler.run",
            timeout: 300,
            events: [
                {
                    sns: {
                        arn: "<redacted>",
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

`s3.ts`

```
export const GetS3Data = async (payload: GetObjectRequest) => {
    try {
        const response = await S3Service.getObject(payload);

        const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const data = [];
            response.Body.on("data", (chunk) => data.push(chunk));
            response.Body.on("err", reject);
            response.Body.once("end", () => resolve(data.join("")));
        });

        return [result, null];
    } catch (err) {
        Logger.error({
            method: "GetS3Data",
            error: err.stack,
        });

        return [null, err];
    }
};
```

`package.json`

```
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.36.0",
```

Comment: Can you please provide your full config including how you create the Lambda so that it is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary what am i missing that you want to see?

Comment: Enough serverless config to replicate the issue, especially how you assign the role to the Lambda please :)

Comment: You can see i am using `iamRoleStatements` which ads the specific rights to the service wide role, is there another way i should be assigning rights ?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the full config :) | your code looks perfectly fine, try changing `Action: ["s3:GetObject"],` to `Action: "s3:GetObject"` perhaps - does that work?

Comment: i don't know why i would do that when actions is typed as  string[]. In any case i can see in the functioin dashboard under configuration --> permissions that this function has s3:GetObject action for the resource.

Comment: So i don't think its a misconfiguration of my lambda permisions...

Comment: Agreed - added an answer

Comment: I fixed this issue, turns out to be something so simple needed to add `/*` at the end of the arn resource

Comment: This is why having a full example is needed - mask, but don't retract ARNs. Glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to add `/*` to the end of the resource

```
Resource: "<redacted>/*",
```

Comment: thanks @Kay ... i got to this after following the aws instructions [How do I allow my Lambda execution role to access my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/). Confusing note on there: "Important: Replace "arn:aws:s3:::AWSDOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*" with your S3 bucket's Amazon Resource Name (ARN)."

Answer (score 2):

**Your `403 Access Denied` error is masking a `404 Not Found` error, as your code & Serverless config looks perfectly fine & should work as expected provided you've specified the resource correctly.**

---

If you do not have correct `s3:ListBucket` permissions, the S3 endpoint will not return a `404 Not Found` error if the object does not exist for the specified key.

`GetObject`'s [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html) highlights this nuance:

> If you have the s3:ListBucket permission on the bucket, Amazon S3 will return an HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error.
>
> If you don’t have the s3:ListBucket permission, Amazon S3 will return an HTTP status code 403 ("access denied") error.

This is to prevent attackers from enumerating public buckets & knowing what objects actually exist in the bucket.

The absence of a 404, in this case, is not allowing information to be leaked on if the object exists or not (just like an `Invalid Credentials` message on a login page as opposed to `Invalid Password` which indicates a user with the provided username exists).

---

Provide the Lambda with permission to carry out the `s3:ListBucket` action to unmask the 404 error and/or ultimately double-check your `GetObjectRequest` to make sure the key is being specified correctly for an object that *does* exist:

```
iam: {
    role: {
        statements: [
            {
                Effect: "Allow",
                Action: ["s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket"],
                Resource: "<redacted>",
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Comment: Adding the extra permission `s3:ListBucket` did not change the outcome. Also the object does exist

Comment: Is the object encrypted? Are your credentials completely correct for S3? Any OU SCPs in action? Any permission boundaries set? If not, then its the object key - something must be wrong with the request

Comment: Is your S3 bucket defined in the `us-east-2` region as I can't see the Serverless config for the bucket?