# Amazon S3 getObject() receives access denied with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get a file stored in Amazon S3 with nodeJS but I get access denied from aws.

> AccessDenied: Access Denied
> at Request.extractError (/home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:699:35)
> at Request.callListeners (/home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
> at Request.emit (/home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
> at Request.emit (/home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
> at Request.transition (/home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
> at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
> at /home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
> at Request. (/home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
> at Request. (/home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
> at Request.callListeners (/home/marc/Disco/Projects/AtlasFitness/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)

Here are is the User policy:
[image]

Get Object expanded:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::atlasfitness-progress-s3/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my CORS policy:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "GET",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Here is the code in NodeJS:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
}) 

export const getFileS3 = (fileKey) => {
    const dowloadParams = {
        Key: fileKey,
        Bucket: 'atlasfitness-progress-s3'
    }

    return s3.getObject(dowloadParams).createReadStream()
}
```

If anyone know how to fix it please I'll be very gratefull for your help, I'm a beginner with AWS.

Comment: Are you 500% sure the file exists and that you are using the correct key and bucket name in the correct region, with the correct access key and secret access key for the user with permissions? Can you please also share the roles assigned to the user please

Comment: Yes, moreover I can upload objects but I can't download them. Yes now I'll share it.

Comment: Yes please :) thank you!

Comment: Done, I think that's what you asked for

Comment: Can you please expand GetObject? What bucket name are you also using in the code?

Comment: Done, hope it will be usefull

Comment: Click JSON please in the top left as I don't speak Spanish unfortunately :D

Comment: Yes hahahah, my fault. Now is with JSON

Comment: Add the `s3:ListBucket` policy - does the error change to a 404 Not Found?

Comment: No, error still the same :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ACL configuration is untouched, your policy is correct, you don't have any restricting bucket policies & your code also looks perfectly fine to me.

Double-check that `fileKey` contains the full key for the object e.g. `folder1/folder2/folder3/myFile.extension`.

A file probably does not exist with the key you've specified - make sure `fileKey`'s value is an exact match of the object's key.

The reason you get a `403 Access Denied` response instead of a `404 Not Found` response is you do not have permissions for `s3:ListBucket`  - read the reasons why AWS returns `403` instead of `404` for security reasons in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69538980/4800344).