# ERROR AccessDenied: Access Denied at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I use nodejs s3 package "aws-sdk" It works fine when I use serverless-offline run on my mac. The s3.getSignedUrl and s3.listObjects function both work fine.

But when I run my deployed app, the s3.getSignedUrl works fine but the s3.listObjects not. I got this error in CloudWatch:

In CloudWatch > Log groups > /aws/lambda/mamahealth-api-stage-userFilesIndex:

```
2021-12-24T02:49:50.965Z    421e054e-d1bf-429a-b73c-402ad21c7bae    ERROR   AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:714:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: 'ap-northeast-1',
  time: 2021-12-24T02:49:50.960Z,
  requestId: 'Q8B79GKAHPHMH3DN',
  extendedRequestId: 'Nhx4ekCzotCSjGXGssFl0lQtyrWf01Gf8416FaqBALA07g3qm31avCIErDPcJWaJt+90xNz8w0o=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 43.44595425080651
}
```

It looks like my aws s3 has permission problem.

My aws-sdk version is 2.995.0

My helpers/s3.ts code:

```
import stream from 'stream';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import axios from 'axios';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import mime from 'mime-types';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'ap-northeast-1',
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

export const uploadFromStream = (key: string, fileExt: string) => {
  const pass = new stream.PassThrough();
  return {
    writeStream: pass,
    promise: s3
      .upload({
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
        Key: key,
        Body: pass,
        ContentType: mime.lookup(fileExt) || undefined,
      })
      .promise(),
  };
};

type S3FileData = {
  lastModified: number;
  id: string;
  fileExt: string;
  size: number;
};

export const listObjects = async (s3Folder: string): Promise<S3FileData[]> => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: `${s3Folder}/`,
  };
  const data = await s3.listObjects(params).promise();
  if (!data.Contents) return [];
  const fileList: S3FileData[] = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < data.Contents.length; index += 1) {
    const content = data.Contents[index];
    const { Size: size } = content;
    const splitedKey: string[] | undefined = content.Key?.split('/');
    const lastModified = moment(content.LastModified).unix();
    const fileFullName =
      (splitedKey && splitedKey[splitedKey.length - 1]) || '';
    const fileFullNameSplited = fileFullName.split('.');
    if (fileFullNameSplited.length < 2 || !size)
      throw Error('no file ext or no size');
    const fileExt = fileFullNameSplited.pop() as string;
    const id = fileFullNameSplited.join();
    fileList.push({ id, fileExt, lastModified, size });
  }
  return fileList;
};

export const uploadFileFromBuffer = async (
  key: string,
  fileExt: string,
  buffer: Buffer,
) => {
  return s3
    .upload({
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
      Key: key,
      Body: buffer,
      ContentType: mime.lookup(fileExt) || undefined,
    })
    .promise();
};

export const uploadFileFromNetwork = async (
  key: string,
  fileExt: string,
  readUrl: string,
) => {
  const { writeStream, promise } = uploadFromStream(key, fileExt);
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: readUrl,
    responseType: 'stream',
  });
  response.data.pipe(writeStream);
  return promise;
};

export enum S3ResourceType {
  image = 'image',
  report = 'report',
}

export const getSystemGeneratedFileS3Key = (
  resourceType: S3ResourceType,
  fileExt: string,
  id?: string,
): string => {
  return `system-generated/${resourceType}/${id || nanoid()}.${fileExt}`;
};

export const getUserUploadedFileS3Key = (
  userId: string,
  fileExt: string,
  id?: string,
) => {
  return `user-uploaded/${userId}/${id || nanoid()}.${fileExt}`;
};

export const downloadFile = async (key: string) => {
  const params: AWS.S3.GetObjectRequest = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
    Key: key,
  };
  const { Body } = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
  return Body;
};

export const deleteFile = (key: string) => {
  const params: AWS.S3.DeleteObjectRequest = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
    Key: key,
  };
  return s3.deleteObject(params).promise();
};

export enum GetSignedUrlOperation {
  getObject = 'getObject',
  putObject = 'putObject',
}

// Change this value to adjust the signed URL's expiration
const URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 300;

export type GetSignedUrlOptions = {
  contentType: string;
};

/**
 * getSignedUrl
 * @param key s3 key
 * @param putOptions If provide putOptions, will return upload file url.
 * @param expirationSeconds Default expiration seconds is 300
 * @returns Signed Url
 */
export const getSignedUrl = (
  key: string,
  putOptions?: GetSignedUrlOptions,
  expirationSeconds?: number,
) => {
  const contentType = putOptions?.contentType;
  const operation = putOptions
    ? GetSignedUrlOperation.putObject
    : GetSignedUrlOperation.getObject;
  return s3.getSignedUrl(operation, {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
    Expires: expirationSeconds || URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS,
    ContentType: contentType,
  });
};
```

Here are my s3 bucket setting:

```
    S3MasterResourceBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        AccelerateConfiguration:
          AccelerationStatus: Suspended
        BucketEncryption:
          ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
            - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                SSEAlgorithm: AES256
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicAcls: TRUE
          BlockPublicPolicy: TRUE
          IgnorePublicAcls: TRUE
          RestrictPublicBuckets: TRUE
        VersioningConfiguration:
          Status: Enabled
```

My iam settings in serverless.yaml:

```
provider:
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - xray:PutTraceSegments
        - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
        - cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup
        - cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes
        - cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth
        - cognito-idp:AdminGetUser
        - s3:PutObject
        - s3:GetObject
        - s3:DeleteObject
        - s3:ListBucket
        - sqs:SendMessage
      Resource:
        - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-ImagePostProcessQueueArn
        - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-CognitoUserPoolMyUserPoolArn
        - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-CognitoUserPoolMyUserPoolArn2
        - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-DynamoDBMasterTableArn
        - "Fn::Join":
            - "/"
            - - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-DynamoDBMasterTableArn
              - "index"
              - "*"
        - "Fn::Join":
            - "/"
            - - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-S3MasterResourceBucketArn
              - "*"
```

I saw Ermiya Eskandary's comment in this question:
[Amazon S3 getObject() receives access denied with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597144/amazon-s3-getobject-receives-access-denied-with-nodejs)
Then I check my configure below:

1. The file exists

Yes, because this code can return data when I use serverless-offline, but when I run deployed app this throw 403 error.

```js
const data = await s3.listObjects(params).promise();
```

2. Use the correct key and bucket name in the correct region.

Yes, the key and bucket names and regions are all correct.

3. with the correct access key and secret access key for the user with permissions?

In my mac, I used this command:

```
aws configure
```

Then I entered my team account's Access Key ID and secret correctly.

4. The roles assigned to the user.

The role is "AdministratorAccess"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line of your IAM role, you grant permissions the lambda function to perform `s3:PutObject`, `s3:GetObject`, `s3:DeleteObject` and `s3:ListBucket` on the `S3MasterResourceBucketArn/*`.

I believe that the first 3 actions and the last one have different resource requirements. For the first 3 (PutObject, GetObject, and DeleteObject) the resource name is correct. For the last one (ListBucket) I believe it must be the arn of the bucket without the star at the end (``S3MasterResourceBucketArn`).

As a good practice, you should split your policy into multiple statements, like:

```
provider:
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource:
        - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-DynamoDBMasterTableArn
        - "Fn::Join":
            - "/"
            - - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-DynamoDBMasterTableArn
              - "index"
              - "*"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup
        - cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes
        - cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth
        - cognito-idp:AdminGetUser
      Resource:
        - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-CognitoUserPoolMyUserPoolArn
        - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-CognitoUserPoolMyUserPoolArn2
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sqs:SendMessage
      Resource:
        - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-ImagePostProcessQueueArn
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:ListBucket
      Resource:
        - Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-S3MasterResourceBucketArn
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
        - s3:GetObject
        - s3:DeleteObject
      Resource:
        - "Fn::Join":
            - "/"
            - - "Fn::ImportValue": mamahealth-api-${self:provider.stage}-S3MasterResourceBucketArn
              - "*"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - xray:PutTraceSegments
        - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
      Resource:
        - "*"
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!  With and without the star is big different.